# Error 500 when performing a query with drive.file scope

Tags: google-drive-api

This code runs fine with the scope "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"

```
File folderEntry = drive.files().get("XXXXj0_srDPPGUEtHaVYtZFljMEk").execute();
String driveQuery = "title = '" + "test" + "' and mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and ";
driveQuery += "'" + folderEntry.getId() + "' in parents";
Files.List request = drive.files().list();
request.setQ(driveQuery);
FileList files = request.execute();
```

But if I change the scope to "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file" in the credentials, and in the API Client access panel, an error 500 is thrown.

```
500 Internal Server Error {   "code" : 500,   "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Internal Error",
    "reason" : "internalError"   } ],   "message" : "Internal Error" }
```

I am using a service account and the parent folder was created by the application.

I do not understand why I cannot perform this query.

Comment: Usually those 500 errors happens randomly. Are you getting it each time you execute this request ?

Comment: Yes, I reproduced it multiple times, all of them threw a 500

Answer (score 0):

I too get the same error. However this workaround does get all the children of a folder I created, until google fixes the query issue I suppose.

```
ChildList list = service.children().list(FILEID).execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be a bit late but... I believe the problem occurs because when you run with the scope https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file you are only allowed to see the files your app has created. However, your query may potentially return metadata that are outside your auth scope.

I had the same problem as well and manage to fix it by *adding* the DRIVE_METADATA_READONLY scope:

```
credential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(this, DriveScopes.DRIVE_FILE, **DriveScopes.DRIVE_METADATA_READONLY**);
```