# How to use the scope https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file correctly

Tags: python, google-sheets-api, service-accounts, gspread

I have tried accessing a Google Sheets file in my Google Drive with this code:

```
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

scope = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('credentials.json', scope)

gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)

wks = gc.open('my_test').sheet1

print(wks.get_all_records())
```

I have then created a spreadsheet called *my_test* in my drive and shared it with the email in *credentials.json*. It then worked. The scope, however, is too broad and I'd like to use

```
scope = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file']
```

instead. But if I change the scope, it cannot find the sheet:

```
File "/home/my_username/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gspread/client.py", line 130, in open
    raise SpreadsheetNotFound
gspread.exceptions.SpreadsheetNotFound
```

Why is that? How can I change it? I have googled around a lot and for most people sharing or resharing the spreadsheet worked. In my case the problem persists.

I also tried this [Error 500 when performing a query with drive.file scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13693617/error-500-when-performing-a-query-with-drive-file-scope) solution of adding a scope for Drive metadata, but that leads to this permissions error, which could be seen as progress (since it finds the file):

```
gspread.exceptions.APIError: {
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "The caller does not have permission",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}
```

However, this error persists even after I set the spreadsheet access to 'public'.

Any hints greatly appreciated!

Oh, and I have a more general question: does the Service Account have access to MY entire drive? Or only to everything that was shared with the Service Account? Cause I have only shared one spreadsheet with it, I am a bit confused on how exactly the permissions work here.

Comment: Please check if this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/49295205/318359 works for you.

Comment: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive' works but I want 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file' for security reasons.

Comment: You need to add the `spreadsheet` scope. `gspread` exposés a global variable with the right scopes under `gspread.auth.DEFAULT_SCOPES​` you can see the spreadsheet scope reauired to access your spreadsheet data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`auth/drive.file` allows operation on an individual files where you have `fileId`. This scope is designed to work along with Google File Picker API so that you would be able to get those `fileId`'s with file picker and later perform your operations.

In your situation you don't have `fileId` thus when you only specify the file name SDK client tries to list the files and doesn't get any results thus it throws 404 error.

For the part:

> However, this error persists even after I set the spreadsheet access to 'public'.

It might be the case that this sheet would be accessible with `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly` scope.